# Why is my exception not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I'm trying to make hangman, I know that there is still a lot to do but I can't figure out why the exception at the bottom isn't working. Here's my code.

```
import random
hideword = 0
player1 = input('''What is player 1's you name? ''')
player2 = input('''What is player 2's you name? ''')
letterlist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k' ,'l' ,'m' ,'n' ,'o' ,'p','q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
print(player1 + 'is first!')
word = input(player2 + ', please turn away, ' + player1 + ' please write a LOWER case word for ' + player2 + ' to guess. ' )
wordsplit = list(word)
while hideword < 50:
    print()
    hideword += 1
while True:
    print(player2 + ', ' + player1 + ''''s word fits into these blanks''')
    print('_ ' * len(wordsplit))
    letter = input(player2 + ' please type a LOWER case letter to guess. ' )
    wordsplit.index(letter)
    letterlist.remove(letter)
    try:
        if letter in wordsplit:
            print('CORRET!')
            print('_ ' * wordsplit.index(letter) + letter + ' _ ' * (len(wordsplit) - wordsplit.index(letter) - 1))
            break
    except ValueError:
        print('Incorrect! Try again')
```

Comment: If your `try: except:` block, what would cause the `ValueError`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, inside your `try` block there is nothing that could throw an exeption, and the best way to handle your situation would probably be to just use an `if..else` as suggested.

However, an exception can already be thrown on these lines:

```
wordsplit.index(letter)
letterlist.remove(letter)
```

This is how you can make it work with `try..except` (just as an example, since `if..else` also works):

```
letter = input(player2 + ' please type a LOWER case letter to guess. ' )

try:
    position = wordsplit.index(letter)
    letterlist.remove(letter)
    print('CORRECT!')  
    print('_ ' * position + letter + ' _ ' * (len(wordsplit) - position - 1))
    break

except ValueError:
    print('Incorrect! Try again')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an `else` there, not `try..except`. The latter is for things that would otherwise cause the program to crash. Checking for membership as you are doing at that point in the program won't cause such an error.

```
try:
    if letter in wordsplit:
        print('CORRET!')
        print('_ ' * wordsplit.index(letter) + letter + ' _ ' * (len(wordsplit) - wordsplit.index(letter) - 1))
        break
except ValueError:
    print('Incorrect! Try again')
```

Change to:

```
if letter in wordsplit:
    print('CORRET!')
    print('_ ' * wordsplit.index(letter) + letter + ' _ ' * (len(wordsplit) - wordsplit.index(letter) - 1))
    break
else:
    print('Incorrect! Try again')
```

Comment: Well I tried that and my code looks like this:                                                             if letter in wordsplit:
        print('CORRET!')
        print('_ ' * wordsplit.index(letter) + letter + ' _ ' * (len(wordsplit) - wordsplit.index(letter) - 1))
        break
    else:
        print('Incorrect! Try again') BUT it still gives me an error when I run the code and type something that is not in the list!

Comment: See my answer for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you're checking : `if letter in wordsplit`, you have no chance of raising a `ValueError` with `wordsplit.index(letter)`.

Thus, no need to raise an Error.
If `letter not in wordsplit`, just follow with an `else`, as has already been said.